# Is there a way to run rapids time series modules (ARIMA, ESM) on multi-gpu?

Tags: gpu, rapids

I have a node with 2 Tesla P100 gpu's on it.

When i run rapids.tsa.ARIMA (or ESM), it will only utilise one of the GPU's.
Is there a way to utilise multi-gpu's for training the models? Like as in rapids-dask-xgboost ?

Comment: No support as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not according to cuml [documentation](https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml#supported-algorithms). For multi-node multi-GPU check the column **Notes** on the table.

Answer (score 1):

A multi node multi gpu implementation of the time series models, Arima and Holtwinters is not present. I would recommend creating a feature request on cuML's github repository (https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml).

Comment: Hi @saloni it's actually their goal to have as many multi node multi gpu algorithms as possible.